# Unable to install PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Using Python 3.11.3
('64bit', 'ELF')

command used

```
pip3 install PySide6
```

also tried

```
pip3 install PySide6==6.5.0
```

Error message:

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide6*